# Flutter url_launcher open Facebook link inside app(Facebook) installed but in IOS it just open facebook and not the link

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, flutter-packages, flutter-ios

I have used Url_launcher package;I want to open Facebook link in facebook app if app installed else the browser.This nicely works in Android but in IOS it only open the Facebook app not the link.

**The code is :**

```
String digital_url= "https://facebook.com/AliForDigitalIsrael/";

    new ListTile(
                            leading: new SvgPicture.asset(
                              'assets/images/ic_menu_fb.svg',
                              height: 24.0,
                              width: 24.0,
                              color: Colors.black54,
                            ),
                            title: new Text(
                              Strings.fbdigital,
                              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                            ),
                            onTap: () async {
                              var fbUrl =
                                  "fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + Strings.digital_url;
                              launchFacebook(fbUrl, Strings.digital_url);
                              hideDrawer();
                            },
    
                          ),
         Future<void> launchFacebook(String fbUrl,String fbWebUrl)
      async {
        try {
          bool launched = await launch(fbUrl, forceSafariVC: false);
          print("Launched Native app $launched");
    
          if (!launched) {
            await launch(fbWebUrl, forceSafariVC: false);
            print("Launched browser $launched");
          }
        } catch (e) {
          await launch(fbWebUrl, forceSafariVC: false);
          print("Inside catch");
        }
      }
```

Comment: Did you edit the info.plist file for iOS ? You have to set the URL Schemes for iOS in order to have deep-link working.

Comment: @danypata no i haven't done that,can you share me any link regrading that.

Comment: https://medium.com/wolox/ios-deep-linking-url-scheme-vs-universal-links-50abd3802f97

Comment: @danypata i don't understand it.Can you please have other link or solution.

Answer (score 11):

My working function:

```
void _launchSocial(String url, String fallbackUrl) async {
  // Don't use canLaunch because of fbProtocolUrl (fb://)
  try {
    bool launched =
        await launch(url, forceSafariVC: false, forceWebView: false);
    if (!launched) {
      await launch(fallbackUrl, forceSafariVC: false, forceWebView: false);
      }
  } catch (e) {
    await launch(fallbackUrl, forceSafariVC: false, forceWebView: false);
  }
}
```

Then in onPressed or onTab:

```
_launchSocial('fb://profile/408834569303957', 'https://www.facebook.com/dorockxl')
```

Don't forget to add fbYOURPAGEID to CFBundleURLSchemes array in Info.plist:

Note: You can use https://lookup-id.com to find your page's id

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb408834569303957</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Btw you can use this method for Twitter and Instagram without an additional setting. Url is enough to open these native apps:

> _launchSocial('https://www.instagram.com/YOURNAME/', '')
>
> _launchSocial('https://twitter.com/YOURNAME', '')

Comment: Which plugin you are using to launch url? because the above code throwing me an error. "Error: Method not found: 'launch'."

Comment: I used url_launcher: ^5.5.0 on Flutter 1.20.1. Flutter is new so versions can have big differences.